# ChartJS -- How do I change scale color when I have to scales?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors, chart.js

[image: Chart with two scales]

I created a nice little chart with two scales using two datasets. I have read the documentation for ChartJS pretty thoroughly, but I can't seem to find out how to add specific colors to the chart scales (numbers). The left scale should be orange and the right one blue. Is this even possible, and if so, how do I do it? I don't think it's necessary for me to supply any source code for the chart itself, but let me know if it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at "Tick Configuration" under ["Scales"](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales). You need to set the `fontColor` option for each axis. Like this:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                fontColor: "#666"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing, it works! Thank you very much for the quick answer.

Comment: I think new documentation link is https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html?h=scales

Answer (score 0):

With Chart.js 4.3.1, the configuration could look like this:

```js
{
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Some title',
                    display: true
                },
                ticks: {
                    color: 'blue' // can also use hex color codes
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See the documentation for [Common tick options to all axes](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.3.1/axes/#common-tick-options-to-all-axes).